# Quill JS - get html selection

Tags: javascript, quill

I would like to ask how get html from selected text? getSelection method returns range which can be used with pure text, but not with HTML.

Comment: https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1829#issuecomment-349298303

Answer (score 1):

You can get html representation from editor with `root.innerHTML` on editor quill variable

```js
var editor = new Quill('#editor', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar'
  },
  theme: 'snow'
});

function dump() {
  var out = editor.root.innerHTML;
  console.log( out );
}

// dump editor content as Parchment NOT html
var b = document.getElementById('clk');
b.addEventListener('click', dump, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Create the toolbar container -->
<div id="toolbar">
  <button class="ql-bold">Bold</button>
  <button class="ql-italic">Italic</button>
</div>

<!-- Create the editor container -->
<div id="editor">
  <p><i>Hello</i> World!</p>
</div><br><br>

<button id="clk">Dump html</button>
```

Comment: thank you , I need html of highlighted / selected text. So in this case if I would highlight Hello and click on dump html I would expect to get <em>Hello</em>.